# Browser does not show extended latin characters

Tags: fonts, special-characters, font-face

I have a problem with archerPro font special chars.
Designer sent me font, I created webfont using fontsquirrl, but it does not show special letters. I have utf-8 in the head of html and use font-face in css to apply it.
Maybe some of you have had the same problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [FontSquirrel WebFont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), you need to check the radio button “Expert” and then, under “Subsetting”, select either suitable Custom Subsetting or No Subsetting. The default is that only characters for “Western Languages” are included—this probably means Windows Latin 1 (windows-1252).